# How to load Multiple 2D Texture in a single 3D Object in ARCORE Using OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore

This is load a single texture place in single Object

```
     Bitmap textureBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
        context.getAssets().open(diffuseTextureAssetName));
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glGenTextures(mTextures.length, mTextures, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);

    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, textureBitmap, 0);
    GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

I need to add Multiple image texture load in to the single 3D object using java code.

Github: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/113

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texture Rendering involves two things - *multi-texturing* and *multiple-textures*. [Multi-texturing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multitexture_with_GLSL) is basically applying multiple textures at the same time to produce the final output.

I guess you are referring to multiple textures,activating one after another to render parts of 3D object. Take a look at [this C++ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681948/multiple-textures-opengl-glut-c) which suggests the approach.

What i have done is to separate faces by the materials they use, make the material and texture active - render all the faces. Repeat the same for each of the set of faces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, If you don't mine attach any of the document about Open GL texture rendering concepts related to java is better else that your preferred language.

Comment: I recently worked on non-open source code around. Still working on extracting it out and sharing on github. Anyway, if you have github account/twitter handle i can message you or contact you i can do or I will update this question with the github account link once i put it up.